# Postman search for a specific value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I’m trying to check response body if there’s a user which has last_name = “Holt” in following [JSON file](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1). with writing a test script in Postman

I’ve already tried:

```
pm.test("Last Name Holt", function () {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    value = pm.expect(jsonData[0].last_name).to.eql("Holt"); });
```

and

```
pm.test("Last Name Holt", function () {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.data[3].last_name).to.eql("Holt");
});
```

2nd code piece returns true but that’s directly looking into data[3] I want to search amongst all last_names in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `some()` method to determine if at least one of the objects in `data` match your condition:

```
pm.test("Last Name Holt", function () {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(responseJson.data.some(o => o.last_name === 'Holt')).to.be.true;
});
```